# SharePoint 2010 and SSRS 2012 Setup and Licensing

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, licensing

I am trying to setup SSRS 2012 in Integrated Mode so that I can attach my SharePoint to it. The issue that I am having is that it seems like Microsoft removed integrated mode and switch to using  SharePoint Application Services instead which means I will now have to purchase full SQL Server licenses for my web servers instead of having one central SQL Server.

With SQL Server 2008 R2 I could simply create a new names instance of SSRS on my SQL Server (which I am licensed using the server model so I can have unlimited instances running on that server) and then in SharePoint I would simply connect it. Therefor SSRS and SQL Engine ran on one server and SharePoint ran on another server.

How do I achieve similar results with SharePoint 2010 and SSRS 2012? It seems to me like I am forced to install SSRS on my Web Servers which is a huge waste of money.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why is installing SSRS on your web servers a 'huge waste of money'? It's common practice if you don't have Kerberos delegation...

Comment: Because you need to purchase an entire SQL Server license for the Web Server, when I already have a SQL Server license on my SQL Server.

Comment: Good point, I'm certain there must be provision for licensing SSRS though, as the only to use the 2012 version is as a Service App.

Comment: Just re-wrote my answer, just remembered how SSRS integrated works with SharePoint :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the post history for my previous version of this answer, it's actually wrong.

SSRS 2012 as a service application is the equivalent of the Add-In in 2010. You can probably install and license in exactly the same way as before, but you install the SErvice Application where you previously installed the Add-In.

Comment: So I would install the "Reporting Services - SharePoint" service on the SQL Server and only install the "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" on the web server?

Comment: That's how I understand it. Give it a try (if you have a dev environment to hand). If I'm wrong, it will fail and say SharePoint isn't installed on the server (as you'll be trying to install SSRS to the SQL box, not the WFE).

Comment: I installed the "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" on the SharePoint server but it isnt showing up in the list of applications. I tried to run Install-SPRSService in the SharePoint Power Shell but it tells me that it is an unrecognized cmdlet. Any ides?

Comment: I got it working. I had to open the PowerShell using -version 2.0 because it was using .NET 4. It is all up and running now and works great! Thanks so much for you help! :)